# many one reduable

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

I A many one reducable to B and given A is decidable then is B decidable ?

preparing for an exam and please let me know if this holds

I understood how if B is decidable then A is decidable

and if A is not decidable then B is not decidable

Comment: People here generally frown on questions where you copy a problem statement and expect others to solve it for you.  We want to help you understand the concepts, but in this case, it's not clear what you've tried or what your particular uncertainty/confusion is.  Just solving the exercise for you probably won't help you or anyone else.  If you edit the question to explain your thoughts and what self-study you've done and what your specific uncertainty is, it's possible the question might be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is reducible to $B$ and $A$ is decidable, then $B$ is not necessarily decidable.

Suppose, for example that $A=\{1\}$ and $B$ is, say, $\{\langle\, B\,\rangle\mid L(M)\text{ is infinite}\}$. It's well-known that $B$ is undecidable and of course $A$ is decidable (any finite language is decidable).

Now let $X$ be a TM for which $L(X)=\Sigma^*$. We could pick $X$ to be a one-state TM where the start state was also an accepting state and on every input symbol there was a transition from the start state to itself, for example. In a similar way, let $Y$ be a particular TM for which $L(Y)=\varnothing$.

We could then produce a many-one map from $A$ to $B$ by:
$$
f(w)=\begin{cases} \langle\, X\,\rangle & \text{if $w=1$}\\
                   \langle\, Y\,\rangle & \text{if $w\ne 1$}
     \end{cases}
$$
Clearly this is a computable function and $w\in A\Longleftrightarrow f(w)\in B$, establishing a reduction from $A$ to $B$ with $A$ decidable and $B$ undecidable.